# How to intercept and record or modify signals between hardware and software

Tags: c#, audio, video

My understanding of how this stuff works is very limited, as I usually just make library calls which make the audio / video magically show up.

I want to be able to do [MITM "attacks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) to programs on my own computer.  (I'd be the guy intercepting signals between the software and the hardware).  This kind of thing could be useful in a number or scenarios.

For instance, for audio:

- XP doesn't have a way to change the audio for specific programs while keeping the others unchange. It only has one audio
  manager across all its programs.  If I could intercept the signal (and
  detect which program it was coming from) I could in theory make my own audio manager.
- I could record conversations, possibly testing out any audio -> text software I may have/create.
- many more.

For video:

- (Primary goal here): record conversations.  I have used a third party program, but I'm guessing what it is doing is taking snapshots because 1) the video is choppy and 2) when the mouse or other thing gets in the way of the video, it records that too.  Wouldn't it be easier just to record the signal going to the video card from the specific program of my interest, then play it back when I want to see it again?

For network traffic:

- For recording traffic to and from my computer, possibly discovering
  programs that are communicating that shouldn't be.

For keyboard/mouse:

- This could be useful for easily creating macros to fill out forms or
  whatever, and I could custom encrypt the data to make sure it's
  secure rather than relying on some third party software.

I'm sure there are many other applications for which this could be useful.

Thanks.